# why do youtube videos stop loading after suspend?

Tags: flash

The question is about a mild problem, plus a curiosity.

When I suspend my netbook (leave it suspended for some hours) and bring it back, my youtube videos keep playing for a short while, then stop. My guess is that, while there is a bit of the video in cache, the plugin cant re-establish the connection to youtube.

Why does this happen ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Maybe its some kind of intrinsic limitation of the http protocol, maybe just something poorly done, or maybe a problem in my setup =P

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that it is more that Youtube has canceled the download stream.  If they didn't, I would think that the bandwidth you were using when you suspended would just be waiting indefinitely for you to reconnect and unavailable to another user.

Just think of how hard it would be for you to watch a Youtube video if 50% of the servers bandwidth was reserved for a bunch of computers that were not going to connect again for the next 12 hours.

I could be wrong here but I would be surprised if I am not at least very close to the truth.

P.S. You would be right about the cache having a bit of the video loaded in the buffer and when that plays out is when the video freezes, but it is not fixable if the video stream that it was loading has ended.